# MS Access Display images based on combo box selection in Report

Tags: image, ms-access, combobox, vba, report

I'm currently creating hazard labels for a chemical inventory. I want the selected pictogram image to show up based on the data from the combo box for each of the records in the report.

My inital method was to place the images on top of each other and hide them. Then have their respective images be visible due to the combo box selection. This works perfectly in a form in the Form_Current event. When you place it in Report_Current event only the selected record image would change when clicked but all the rest are blank.

The code:

```
If GHS_Selection_1.Value = "1" Then
    expos.Visible = False
    flamme.Visible = False
    rondflam.Visible = False
    bottle.Visible = False
    skull.Visible = False
    exclam.Visible = False
    acid.Visible = False
    silhouete.Visible = False
    aquatic.Visible = False
ElseIf GHS_Selection_1.Value = "2" Then
    expos.Visible = True
    flamme.Visible = False
    rondflam.Visible = False
    bottle.Visible = False
    skull.Visible = False
    exclam.Visible = False
    acid.Visible = False
    silhouete.Visible = False
    aquatic.Visible = False
ElseIf GHS_Selection_1.Value = "3" Then
    expos.Visible = False
    flamme.Visible = True
    rondflam.Visible = False
    bottle.Visible = False
    skull.Visible = False
    exclam.Visible = False
    acid.Visible = False
    silhouete.Visible = False
    aquatic.Visible = False 
    ...etc
```

Is there a better method for this or improvements? OLE objects or unbounded images boxes? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
In a somewhat related issue, is there a way I can fill a whole page or many pages with the same record, and another when you select a range of chemicals for printing from a subform/table from a click of a button.

Comment: The report is static so can you not join the image in the report data source per record? Then simply display it as a image field? Create a table that links the image to the GHS_Selection and you should be good to go. That would also simplify your forms code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, can you explain it in more depth? Do I link the images through the combo box table?

Comment: You can store bitmap images as a OLE object within a table. If you linked that to an Image Name or ID you could then create a query to include that in your data, and display it per record based on the value in the GHS_Selection field. You could probably bring it into a hidden combo box column as well but I've never tried that.

Comment: Hans a regular contributor here has a sample (use the one in the last post) here http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=1693 that might help you

Comment: If you want to conditionally display controls holding image on report, then code must be in Detail section Format event. Be aware Format event only triggers in PrintPreview or direct to printer.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for you suggestion, it helped me solve the issue.